# Python how to override a method defined in a module of a third party library

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've installed a third party library [tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org) by **pip** and need to override a **method**, say `to_unicode` defined in the global scope of a module say `tornado.escape`. So that all calls to that method will use my overridden version. Or maybe, I would want to control it so that only my code will use the overridden version.

If it had been defined inside a class, I'd have no problem to subclass it and override the method! But since this is just a method, I'm wondering how to override it.

Surprisingly, I found not suitable solution in SO, is this kind of impossible to achieve?

Comment: you probably should define a class that heritates from tornado and there redefine your wanted method so it will be called instead of the parent's one

Comment: Like I mentioned, the method I want to override is NOT defined inside any class, rather defined in the module's global scope! So how I'm going to override if there's no class in the first place?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can simply rebind the name of an object (in this case, a module-level function) to a different object. For example, [if you want to have `math.cos` work with degrees instead of radians](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/792365/22262), you could do

```
>>> import math
>>> math.cos(90)
-0.4480736161291701
>>> old_cos = math.cos
>>> def new_cos(degrees):
...     return old_cos(math.radians(degrees))
...
>>> math.cos = new_cos
>>> math.cos(90)
6.123233995736766e-17
```

However, that might cause problems to other functions that use that module...

Comment: @thefourtheye What is a "pure" function?

Comment: is this way so-called "monkey patch"?

Comment: @CSJ Yes this is called monkey-patching.