# Override python package util method

Tags: python, django, package, overriding

I've installed a package in my Django project, let's say `pip install somepackage`

This package comes with some modified views, so I do:

```
class MyView(somepackage.CustomView):
    ...
```

But there's some method in `somepackage.utils` (`somepackage.utils.somemethod`) that I need to customize. If this were a method in `somepackage.CustomView` I could do:

```
class MyView(somepackage.CustomView):

    def somemethod(...):
        ...
```

But it's not.

How can I override that util's method?

Comment: You want to replace _that_ method with your own? It's not a method, it's function in `sompackage.utils` module.

Comment: You can do monkey patch. https://web.archive.org/web/20120730014107/http://wiki.zope.org/zope2/MonkeyPatch

Comment: @MichałF Yes, I found something there that I need to replace, I could write a new code for that method without breaking anything else, but I don't know how

Comment: @ShangWang What does 'monkey patch' means? Sorry but I don't know.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-a-monkey-patch

Comment: @ShangWang That look like something made by a monkey, but I need to pass one param to this method, I think this is for callable method without params, right?

Comment: I'm giving this straight from head: `somepackage.utils.__old_somemethod = somepackage.utils,_old_somemethod` then you need to write your function and assign it for `somepackage.utils.somemethod`. This should work if your `somepackage` is written in pure Python. If the `__old_somemethod` don't work straightway, you may need to amend module's __dict__ first. Google is your friend if you now what you're looking for.

Comment: There's also this one that should meet what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23646826/python-how-to-override-a-method-defined-in-a-module-of-a-third-party-library

Comment: @ShangWang a monkey patch worked, thanks, consider give it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the discussion goes, I think we can do "monkey patch" on the module level functions, which basically replaces the function with your version. There's already an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23646826/python-how-to-override-a-method-defined-in-a-module-of-a-third-party-library?answertab=active#tab-top) that explains this, but quote it here (replace `math` with `somepackage.utils`):

```
>>> import math
>>> math.cos(90)
-0.4480736161291701
>>> old_cos = math.cos
>>> def new_cos(degrees):
...     return old_cos(math.radians(degrees))
...
>>> math.cos = new_cos
>>> math.cos(90)
6.123233995736766e-17
```