# How to override error logging with method arguments it propagates from in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, metaprogramming

I would like to inject the arguments of a method which fire an error level log into the log.

I looked at this question and I think the inspect library could be a good choice to get the arguments of the method: [Getting method parameter names in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218616/getting-method-parameter-names-in-python)

```
import inspect

def add(x,y):
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    try:
        print(frame.f_locals)
    finally:
        del frame
    return x+y

Running: add(4,5)
Returns: {'frame': , 'y': 5, 'x': 4}
```

Though ideally I would only like to call the above inspect code to add the info to the error level logs automatically and only when they are called somehow overwriting the error logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question. Basically you can:

- Use [`inspect.stack`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.stack) to get the caller frame from the new `error` function
- Overwrite the default [`logging.error`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.error) function as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23646826/python-how-to-override-a-method-defined-in-a-module-of-a-third-party-library)
- Use [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) to make the wrapper function look like the wrapped function

The result looks like this:

```
from functools import wraps
import logging
import inspect

# save the old logging.error function
__logging_error = logging.error

@wraps(logging.error)
def error(msg, *args, **kwargs):
    __logging_error(msg, *args, **kwargs)
    caller = inspect.stack()[1]
    caller_frame = caller[0]
    __logging_error('args: %s' % caller_frame.f_locals)

# overwrite the default logging.error
logging.error = error
```

Now the code:

```
def add(x, y):
    logging.error('this is an error')
    return x + y

add(4, 5)
```

outputs:

```
ERROR:root:this is an error
ERROR:root:args: {'y': 5, 'x': 4}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, your code is throwing a RecursionError but stepping back in the stack is a simple solution for my problem.

Comment: @chrisvlll: this is curious, it doesn't throw anything to me. Try the whole script here: https://gist.github.com/enricobacis/83ca7bf163b27e95eb28288e0756f8cc

Comment: Apologies I ran it multiple times in ipython and due to the monkey patch it threw a RecursionError