# monkey-patch object coming from callback

Tags: python

Note: I have searched and read [how to override a method defined in a module of a third party library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23646826/python-how-to-override-a-method-defined-in-a-module-of-a-third-party-library).

The Python Telegram bot library utilizes callbacks/handlers. If we define this:

```
self.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", self.help))
```

Then `self.help()` will receive the args `bot` and `update` when a certain event occurs.

One of those args, `bot`, has a method called `send_message`. I want to prefix all of my bot's messages with a certain string. What I *don't* want:

1. Do it manually each time in `bot.send_message`. like this: `send_message(text= prefix + " Hello")`.
2. Having to monkey patch the `bot.send_message` method, like suggested in the answer to the aforementioned question. I have several other methods besides `self.help()` and this doesn't seem to abide the DRY rule.

The challenge here seems to be that I'm receiving a new instance of `bot` each time the callback is fired.

What are my options, if any?

I'm calling `bot.message()` in a variety of ways (mixed args and kwargs). For example, `parse_mode` can be absent in some calls.

```
bot.send_message(
            chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
            text=txt,
            parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.MARKDOWN,
        )
```

Comment: Edit your local installation of `.../site_packages/telegram/bot.py` (or whatever the filename is), and insert the desired text in the `send_message()` function.

Comment: @JohnGordon - that sounds very naughty, is it the only DRY way?

Comment: @JohnGordon - also, my script will have to be portable, so even that doesn't really sound too attractive.

Comment: What function are you calling from your code?  Is it `bot.send_message()`, or `bot.help()`, or some other function?

Comment: @JohnGordon I am calling bot.send_message(), bot is an arg in self.help(), which is invoked by a callback.

Comment: @JohnGordon could a decorator help here?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are calling `bot.send_message()` directly from your code.  Presumably it's something like this:

```
bot = Bot(...)
bot.send_message("something")
```

You could make your own wrapper function that takes the bot instance and the message, and inserts the desired extra text:

```
def send_message_plus(bot, message):
    bot.send_message("This is extra " + message)
```

Then you would just call the wrapper function:

```
send_message_plus(bot, message)
```

Comment: `send_message()` takes (potentially) many `args` and `kwargs`

Comment: When you call it yourself, are you actually using args and kwargs?  Or do you just use it with one plain string, as in your example?

Comment: You could modify the wrapper function to add the kwargs, but at that point it seems like less effort to forget about the wrapper function and just add the text to each call.

Comment: Yep. Thanks for your help.