# Set Decimal Point Precision in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like this -

**df**

```
    A   B
0   1   2
1   2   3
2   3   4
```

I'd like to create a function that could do the following -

```
df.numberformat['A']='0.2f'
```

I know this can be done using `pandas.set_option('display.float_format', '{:.2f}'.format)`. However I'd like to create a **class** that inherits `pandas.DataFrame` and create a functionality as mentioned before.

Any ideas.

Comment: Try this: https://www.thedigitalcatonline.com/blog/2014/05/19/method-overriding-in-python/#method-overriding-in-action or have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23646826/python-how-to-override-a-method-defined-in-a-module-of-a-third-party-library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used some help from the links provided by @droebi and wrote a `CustomDataFrame` class that inherits the pandas dataframe and created a custom numberformat method that could format the columns as per user request.

```
class CustomDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):          
    def __init__(self,df):
        super().__init__(df)
        self.numberformat=self.format
        
    def format(self, column, format_):
        return pd.DataFrame(self[column]).astype(float).applymap(format_.format)
```

The `a` object below is a dataframe but of class `CustomDataFrame` -

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3],"B":[2,3,4]})
a=CustomDataFrame(df)
a.numberformat('A','{:,.2f}')
```

I couldn't use the `Styler` object as I needed the formatting to be kept and the formatted data to be used further in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Pandas has a table visualization `DataFrame.style` attribute which returns a Styler object.
the format function has a precision argument to specifically help formatting floats.

So all you have to do is

```
df.style.format(precision=0)
```

You can also pass in the specifier directly if you wish to

```
 df.style.format('{:.0f}')
```

Comment: I think `precision` only works on floats, not ints, so might have to convert dtype first..